# Windows Fax Server/Client Application

Tags: windows, fax

I'm currently looking for a fax solution for a small business. Basically we need users to be able to send/receive faxes from their desktop. Ideally users could have their own numbers and receive faxes directed at them right at their desktops. Does anyone have any recommendations for this? I know there is the ever-popular Hylafax, but I don't have much time to implement this. I have been looking at [Snappy Fax](http://www.snappysoftware.com/index.html), but I'm not sure if it supports receiving directly to the user's clients (waiting for sales to get back to me.

Answer (score 1):

There's always eFax.

http://www.efax.com/products/internet-fax

Comment: Yea, I'm looking in to MetroFax https://www.metrohispeed.com/soho/ they are quite a bit cheaper. Other than spending $80,000 on a RightFax license/server/brooktrout cards I don't think we have any other option

Answer (score 0):

https://serverfault.com/questions/1995/free-fax-client-recommendation

Everybody loves free.  But then again, you don't get as much support...

Comment: I'm not looking for a desktop client. I'm looking for a central fax server that can send off faxes to individual users desktops.

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the market for a new server, then Windows Small Server Business has a pretty decent fax server built in. In the SBS 2003 R2 version (which is what we run), incoming faxes can be routed to a single email address, a SharePoint library, a file folder and/or directly to a printer.

Recently, I've been evaluating [GFI FAXMaker](http://www.gfi.com/faxmaker) and it seems like a good choice if you're needing more features and customization out of your fax server. I think its most useful features are its extensive routing capabilities, saving fax attachments as either TIF or PDF (SBS only does TIF), half decent Fax OCR (text is saved as email text body but not embedded in PDFs. grrr...), and better fax archiving. If you don't have SBS, the a single line, single user license of FAXMaker is a painless $109.

Comment: The main thing I'm looking for here is the ability to support a lot of users with only a few modems and I'm not sure how the commercial tools handle this. I can have the DID pushed to callerID by our MGCP phone system and I know I can parse that with Hylafax. Do you know if WS for SB can handle that?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get those acronyms in your last sentence...

As for many users using a few modems, it appears that Small Business Server does support multiple lines. Outgoing, it will try to dial out in the order of outgoing fax modem devices defined. (ie. If 1st modem is busy, use the 2nd modem, etc). For incoming, you can assign individual routing options per fax device (ie. 1st line to admin email, 2nd line to sales email address & to shared folder, etc)

I don't see any limit in terms of fax devices you can have. The number of users is tied to the CAL license for the SBS server.